# How to extract text from large tiff images using tessract in unix?

Tags: unix, image-processing, text-extraction

i am using tessract api to extract the text from images. 
I have a large tiff image of 6264x65985 resolution.
It gives me error for large resolution.
Any ideas/suggestions?t

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

6264x65985 resolution exceeds Tesseract limits.The maximum width and height are 32767. Resize or rescale your image and try again.

Comment: @Karthick vadivel: could you accept answer and upvote please?